# Can't extract named group in php PCRE regexp using pattern with DEFINE condition

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, pcre

I have a trouble with capturing named classes using PECL regexpr.
Pattern is huge enough, and i use DEFINE condition
like here: https://regex101.com/library/gJ7pU0

*About PCRE regexp: http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt see chapter "Defining subpatterns for use by reference only" for more about DEFINE condition.*

For example I have **data**:

```
1234-abcd-odd
5678-efgh-even
5678-ijkl-odd
9012-wzyz-even
```

and want extract numerical and literal part of even lines

**Pattern**

```
/(?(DEFINE)
    (?<even> (?&numbers) - (?&letters) - even )
        (?<numbers> \d{4} )
        (?<letters> \w{4} )
)
^(?&even)$
/xm
```

online example: https://regex101.com/r/BidEf2/2

I have php code: https://3v4l.org/JXRuH

```
<?php
$re = <<< REG
/(?(DEFINE)
    (?<even> (?&numbers) - (?&letters) - even )
        (?<numbers> \d{4} )
        (?<letters> \w{4} )
)
^(?&even)$
/xm
REG;


$str = <<< STR
1234-abcd-odd
5678-efgh-even
5678-ijkl-odd
9012-wzyz-even
STR;

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

// Print the entire match result
print_r($matches);
```

It outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5678-efgh-even
            [1] => 9012-wzyz-even
        )

    [even] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
        )

    [numbers] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
        )

    [letters] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] =>
        )

)
```

Pattern matches, and array keys for named classes created, but empty. Result array should have

```
[0] => strings that matched full pattern
[1] => first captured string
[2] => second captured string
...
[several string keys for named groups]
```

But only [0] key filled.

What's wrong and can i use DEFINE condition and named groups together?

Comment: The point is that the captures inside `DEFINE`  group are not kept in the memory. You won't be able to access those captures if you do not use them in the actual consuming part of the pattern.